# EventHook AFTER the view has completely re-rendered

Tags: angular

I am trying to include webpack into an Angular2 project and run into a problem I already faced in previous scenarios. The common problem is that I need to wait until the view is completely rendered and THEN perform some action. I know there is the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook which is however only triggered the first time the view is rendered. When it is being re-rendered because of data changes within the component, its not being called again. Take a look at my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select('trips').subscribe(trips => {
    // forces view to re-render
    this.trips = trips;

    // doesn't work because the updated DOM doesn't exist yet
    let Packery: any = require('packery');
    new Packery(this.grid.nativeElement, {
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      gutter: 10
    });
  });

  this.store.dispatch(new TripActions.LoadTrips());
}
```

A slight modification makes the code work as expected (most of the time) but comes with the caveat that the website looks extremly ugly for about a second every time new data is loaded, which is not a solution. It shows the problem however.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select('trips').subscribe(trips => {
    // forces view to re-render
    this.trips = trips;


    setTimeout(() => {      
      // now it works (most of the time) because after 0.5s
      // the updated DOM elements usually exist...
      let Packery: any = require('packery');
      new Packery(this.grid.nativeElement, {
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        gutter: 10
      });
    }, 500);
  });    

  this.store.dispatch(new TripActions.LoadTrips());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is `ngAfterViewChecked()`. Here's a quote from the documentation.

> Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views.
>   Called after the `ngAfterViewInit` and every subsequent
>   `ngAfterContentChecked()`.

This means it's not only called once after initialization, but also after every `ngAfterContentChecked()` that is called when your data changes. On every call you can check if your data is already there and then respond with your code. One problem is that it may be called even after you've done your Packery things, which is why you have to make sure that you only do that once.

Check the [lifecycle hook page](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) out for more information.

Comment: Hmm I tried ngAfterViewChecked but whatever I put into that callback somehow causes an infinite cycle during server side renderering :-/
I guess I will open a new thread to tackle that issue?